# JavaFX8- Anchoring TableView column's ContextMenu immediately below the the column's header?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am trying to put some node controls in the context menu for a table column. However, when I right click the table header to trigger the ContextMenu, it puts the top-left corner on the cursor location. Is there an easy way to anchor the ContextMenu's top-left corner to the bottom-left corner of the TableHeader? I can't find the table header anywhere in the TableView's properties.

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.setAnchorLocation(... what do I anchor to?);

contextMenu.getItems().add(FilterPanel.getInMenuItem(this));
tableColumn.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

Also, is there a way to allow users to resize the ContextMenu by dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for my solution I had to dig deep into the `TableView`s Skin.

First we have to register for the `TableView`s skin, so we get notified as soon as it has been set up:

```
tableView.skinProperty().addListener((w, o, n) -> {
    if (n instanceof TableViewSkin) {
        TableViewSkin<?> skin = (TableViewSkin<?>) n;
            checkChangeContextMenu(skin, column);
    }
});
```

And secondly we have the magic code:

```
private static void checkChangeContextMenu(TableViewSkin<?> skin, TableColumn<?, ?> column) {
    NestedTableColumnHeader header = skin.getTableHeaderRow()
            .getRootHeader();
    header.getColumnHeaders().addListener((Observable obs) -> changeContextMenu(header,column));
    changeContextMenu(header, column);
}

private static void changeContextMenu(NestedTableColumnHeader header, TableColumn<?, ?> column) {
    TableColumnHeader headerSkin = scan(column, header);
    if (headerSkin != null) {
        headerSkin.setOnContextMenuRequested(ev -> {
            ContextMenu cMenu = column.getContextMenu();
            if (cMenu != null) {
                cMenu.show(headerSkin, Side.BOTTOM, 5, 5);
            }
            ev.consume();
        });
    }
}

private static TableColumnHeader scan(TableColumn<?, ?> search,
        TableColumnHeader header) {
    // firstly test that the parent isn't what we are looking for
    if (search.equals(header.getTableColumn())) {
        return header;
    }

    if (header instanceof NestedTableColumnHeader) {
        NestedTableColumnHeader parent = (NestedTableColumnHeader) header;
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getColumnHeaders().size(); i++) {
            TableColumnHeader result = scan(search, parent
                    .getColumnHeaders().get(i));
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Essentially what we are doing here:

1. Register for TableHeader skin updates
2. Search for the skin of our `TableColumn`
3. Change the behavior of how the `ContextMenu` is shown from absolute positioning by mouse coordinates to relative positioning below the TableColumnHeader`s Skin.

Comment: This is certainly suboptimal and I hope the JavaFX team will consider exposing table header properties in the future. But I'm glad there is a solution and I'll play with your code above. I'll mark it if it works.